# How to install avahi on m2 macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have some question about installing avahi.

I need avahi demon because of access with pc name.

so, I want to configure avahi on mac, broadcast mac's pc name.

First, I try with [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/avahi), but homebrew only support x64 linux.

Second, I try with [macport](https://ports.macports.org/port/avahi/). I followed their installations. I use `find launchctl list | grep avahi` to check running daemons. I can find running daemons. but, `ps aux | grep avahi` cannot find avahi daemons.

and, I check a avahi-daemon file, `/opt/local/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`, but I can't find file.

How can I install and set avahi on m2 macbook? I really need to broadcast macbook's pc name because I want to allow other pc could access my macbook only with pc name.

Comment: This feels rather an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Why do you need Avahi? macOS has its own zeroconf equivalent, [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)

Comment: @Tetsujin well, I can't find my mac name in virtual machine. I installed bonjour service on virtual machine to solve problem. so, I think if I use avahi, then I can use zeroconf between mac and virtual machine. I can access mac with real mac's IP, but I can't access with mac's name such as "~~~.local"

Comment: You should ask a question based on your actual problem, not on your supposed solution to that problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, I didn't know mac provides zeroconf equivalent, so I will search my firewall or network adaptor's settings, then I will ask later if I couldn't solve yet.

Comment: This is not a XY Problem, this is an absolutely valid question which you don't know the answer to, and instead of providing any answer you put the person in the wrong direction and by sounding like an a-hole hinders someone else from answering. Congratulations.